# How to append value to xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Posttype1 xmlns="http://www.company.com/path" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <type1Set>
    <type1 action="Add">
      <CLASS maxvalue="type1">type1</CLASS>
      <CREATEDBY>user</CREATEDBY>
      <LANGCODE>EN</LANGCODE>
      <STATUS>NEW</STATUS>
      <ID>1073</ID>
    </type1>
  </type1Set>
</Posttype1>
```

In this xml Posttype1 has to be converted to Puttype1 and ID value have to be appended with 99.
The output should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Puttype1 xmlns="http://www.company.com/path" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <type1Set>
    <type1 action="Add">
      <CLASS maxvalue="type1">type1</CLASS>
      <CREATEDBY>user</CREATEDBY>
      <LANGCODE>EN</LANGCODE>
      <STATUS>NEW</STATUS>
      <ID>991073</ID>
    </type1>
  </type1Set>
</Posttype1>
```

The Posttype1 is converted using xslt , but when trying to append 99 I am unable to reach the Id.

The XSLT used is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:comp="http://www.company.com/path" version="1.0" >
<xsl:template match="comp:Postype1 ">
    <xsl:element name="Puttype1 ">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Puttype1/type1Set/type1/ID">
<xsl:number>99</xsl:number>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This give the following output

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Puttype1 >
  <type1Set xmlns="http://www.company.com/path" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <type1 action="Add">
      <CLASS maxvalue="type1">type1</CLASS>
      <CREATEDBY>user</CREATEDBY>
      <LANGCODE>EN</LANGCODE>
<STATUS>NEW</STATUS>
   <ID>1073</ID>
   </type1>
   </type1Set>
   </Posttype1>
```

As you can see the xmlns and xmlns:xsi is moving to the child tag, Can someone tell me why this is happening and I don't know how to append the integer.

P.S. I also tried

```
<xsl:template match="comp:Postype1 ">
<xsl:element name="Puttype1 ">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

It moved the xmlns tag to parent but xmlns:xsi is still in child.

Comment: `<xsl:number>99</xsl:number>` is not valid in XSLT. The element must be empty. If you want to use `xsl:number` to insert an explicit number, it needs to be `<xsl:number value="99"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:comp="http://www.company.com/path">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comp:Postype1 ">
    <Puttype1 xmlns="http://www.company.com/path">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Puttype1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comp:ID">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('99', . )"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is there a way to append the 99 only if id doesn't start with 99 and length greater than 2.

Comment: Sure. Start your template with `<xsl:template match="comp:ID[not(starts-with(., '99')) and string-length(.) > 2]">`.